# TypeError: Cannot destructure property id of req.params as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, body-parser

I'm trying to get a user profile from a database and return it as a json object when the profile url (localhost:3000/Profile/1) is ran. but i am getting this error: **TypeError: Cannot destructure property *id* of  *req.params* as it is undefined.**

here is the code in the express server.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/Profile/:id', (res,req) =>{
    const {id} = req.params;
    db.select('*').from('user').where({id})
    .then(user => {
    res.json(user[0])})
})
```

i used postman to  send the get request.

Comment: `req.params.id` it will work

Comment: What does `console.log( req.params )` returns inside `app.get`?

Comment: res and req are the wrong way around in your function it should be `(req, res) => { ...`

Comment: It turns out @George was right, silly mistake on my side by the way. immediately I changed req and res, it worked. Thank you to everyone. Special thanks to George.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passing the wrong parameters to the `get` function

E.g.

```js
// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

In your case

```js
app.get('/Profile/:id', (req, res) =>{
   console.log(req.params)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see your error man, you put in the function (res, res) and should be (req,res).

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters is Request, Response so you have to do this:

```
app.get('/profile/:id', (request, response) => {
    const { id } = request.params;
    db.select('*').from('user').where({id}).then(
       user => {
           res.json(user[0])
       });
});
```